# Angular JS UI Accordions Heading Updated Only When Clicked

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, accordion

Having a little issue with the [AngularJS UI Accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) component. The Accordion does not seem to reflect the value of the $scope variable I've set and only reflects it when I have clicked on the component itself on the page.

In my Kendo UI Grid component, I have defined the options as follows:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        data: $scope.reviews,
        pageSize: 5
    },
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    change: gridSelected,
    selectable: 'row',
    columns: [
        { field: "field1", title: "Field 1"},
        { field: "field2", title: "Field 2"},
        { field: "field3", title: "Field 3"},
        { field: "field4", title: "Field 4"},
        { field: "field5", title: "Field 5"},
        { field: "field6", title: "Field 6"},
        { field: "field7", title: "Field 7"},
        { field: "field8", title: "Field 8"}
    ]
};
```

And in my function:

```
function gridSelected(arg) {
    var selectedRow = this.select();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRow[0]);

    $scope.fld1 = dataItem.field1;
    $scope.fld2 = dataItem.field2;

    console.log($scope.fld1);
    console.log($scope.fld1);
};
```

From the console.log, I can verify that the value for $scope.fld1 and $scope.fld2 are both correct as the selected row in the Kendo grid.

My accordion is defined as follows:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-right:-5px">
    <accordion>
        <accordion-group heading="{{fld1}}" >
            Contains Items for First Accordion
        </accordion-group>

    </accordion>

    <accordion>
        <accordion-group heading="{{fld2}}">
            Contains Items for Second Accordion
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

I am not really sure why the text for fld1 and fld2 only appears when I click on any of the following accordion component (which upon clicking, updates both the heading text).

UPDATE:
I am starting to think that this might be a kendoUI issue related, as I've tried with a normal ui-grid and the $scope variable is updated and reflected in the UI immediately. Still digging deeper though.

Comment: Are you using the Angular directives for Kendo UI Grid?

Comment: Yes, I am using the directives and examples provided from KendoUI Grid.

Comment: Try wrapping it like this: `$scope.$apply(function () { $scope.fld1 = dataItem.field1; $scope.fld2 = dataItem.field2; });`. I would guess it wouldn't be needed when using the Angular Kendo directives, but you never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure this out through this article:

[A Few Angular Kendo UI Best Practices](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-02-26/a-few-angular-kendo-ui-best-practices)

Practically I was missing the $apply call.